# Difference Between Plugin, Addon, and Helper Application

Tags: browser, definition

I am trying to understand classification/naming of scripts,
I havent found any software vocabulary online that I can read,
I have many scripts which my own, and from open sources.
I want to put my script to correct folders.

Whats difference between those concepts in practice?

Answer (score 1):

Plugins are the complete programs and these can be installed in your system and can be used in browser whereas add-ons are not complete programs ,these are used to add functionality to your browser.
for example, Flash Player is a plugin which can be installed in your system as well in browser to play video,
InPrivate Filtering is an add-on which is used in some browser to provide privacy.
So, add-ons provide additional and limited functionality to your browser.

Comment: by helper, do you mean browser helper objects?

Comment: No, not browser helper object, just word of Helper in coding vocabulary

Comment: ok, helper classes are normal classes which we can write to provide functionality to our code.Like, you are reading a file which is containing some pattern and there are many files which are used in your application then you will write a separate class for that pattern and now you can use that class anywhere ,where you want to read that pattern.

Comment: sorry, by mistake i hit enter. Apologies for that.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, it is not about plugins, or addons of browser or, other softwares. I mean the type of scripts..

Comment: No sir, i did not misunderstood your question, plugins and addons meanings are same in scripts as well. :)